# Почему в мобильной версии в слайдере цен не работает ползунок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Нашел в нете слайдер цен
www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/ui/ui-slider
Но не могу понять почему в моб версии в хроме (да и вообще в режиме разработчика в Chrome) нельзя подвинуть звездочки, причем если кликать на линии все работает. Также работает если менять значения в полях.
В Firefox в моб версии все работает нормально.

Ниже код слайдера цен

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
/* слайдер цен */

jQuery("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 30000,
  values: [0,30000],
  range: true,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    jQuery("input#minCost").val(jQuery("#slider").slider("values",0));
    jQuery("input#maxCost").val(jQuery("#slider").slider("values",1));

    },
    slide: function(event, ui){
    jQuery("input#minCost").val(jQuery("#slider").slider("values",0));
    jQuery("input#maxCost").val(jQuery("#slider").slider("values",1));
    }
});

jQuery("input#minCost").change(function(){

  var value1=jQuery("input#minCost").val();
  var value2=jQuery("input#maxCost").val();

    if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
    value1 = value2;
    jQuery("input#minCost").val(value1);
  }
  jQuery("#slider").slider("values",0,value1);
});


jQuery("input#maxCost").change(function(){

  var value1=jQuery("input#minCost").val();
  var value2=jQuery("input#maxCost").val();

  if (value2 > 30000) { value2 = 30000; jQuery("input#maxCost").val(30000)}

  if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
    value2 = value1;
    jQuery("input#maxCost").val(value2);
  }
  jQuery("#slider").slider("values",1,value2);
});



// фильтрация ввода в поля
  jQuery('#minCost, #maxCost').keypress(function(event){
    var key, keyChar;
    if(!event) var event = window.event;

    if (event.keyCode) key = event.keyCode;
    else if(event.which) key = event.which;

    if(key==null || key==0 || key==8 || key==13 || key==9 || key==46 || key==37 || key==39 ) return true;
    keyChar=String.fromCharCode(key);

    if(!/\d/.test(keyChar)) return false;

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.
Нужно подключить [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) после подключения jQuery UI